# Broadcast Receiver not receiving intent (RemoteViews / PendingIntent)

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent, android-broadcast, android-remoteview

I am working on a custom notification which contains two buttons. I am using RemoteViews and used PendingIntent so that it will be received in the broadcast receiver. It is working fine in Huawei device but not working in Oppo & Infinix devices.

I am registering broadcast receiver like this in **manifest**:

```
<receiver android:name="com.appedia.flashlight.torch.Notification_Receiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="Notification_Flashlight"></action>
                <action android:name="Notification_SOS"></action>
                <action android:name="Notification_Delete"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Using these methods in the **Main Activity** for notification:

```
public void Notification()
        {
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            builder.setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setCustomContentView(remoteViews)
                    .setDeleteIntent(delete_pending_intent)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            {
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.flashlight);
            }
            else
            {
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            }
    
    
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            {
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, importance);
                assert notificationManager != null;
                builder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }
    
            assert notificationManager != null;
        }
    
        public void NotificationItemsClickIntent()
        {
            Intent notification_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notification_intent, 0);
    
            Intent notification_deleted_intent = new Intent("Notification_Delete");
            notification_deleted_intent.putExtra("notification_delete", "notification_delete");
            delete_pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, notification_deleted_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    
    
            /* Pending Intent for Notification Flashlight Button */
            //Intent with flashlight button for triggering Broadcast Receiver when clicked from notification bar
            Intent notification_flashlight_intent = new Intent("Notification_Flashlight");
            notification_flashlight_intent.putExtra("notification_flashlight", "Flashlight");
    
            //start flashlight when notification bar button is clicked
            PendingIntent notification_flashlight_button = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,notification_flashlight_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_flashlight_button, notification_flashlight_button);
    
            /* Pending Intent for Notification SOS Button */
            //Intent with sos button for triggering Broadcast Receiver when clicked from notification bar
            Intent notification_sos_intent = new Intent("Notification_SOS");
            notification_sos_intent.putExtra("notification_sos", "SOS");
    
            //start flashlight when notification bar button is clicked
            PendingIntent notification_sos_button = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,notification_sos_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_sos_button, notification_sos_button);
        }
    
        //broadcast receiver for getting battery percentage
        private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    
                boolean isPlugged;
    
                int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_battery_percent,String.valueOf(level) + "%");
    
                int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
                isPlugged = plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC || plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    
                if(isPlugged)
                {
                    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_battery_text, "Charging");
                }
                else
                {
                    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_battery_text, "Discharging");
                }
    
                NotificationItemsClickIntent();
                Notification();
                notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

                unregisterReceiver(mBatInfoReceiver);
                }
            };
```

Starting notification service and registering broadcast receiver for battery information like this in onCreate of MainActivity:

```
//Starting Notification Service
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.notification_bar);

    //for getting battery percentage (shows notification)
        this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

**Notification Broadcast Receiver:**

```
public class Notification_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

String notification_flashlight, notification_sos, notification_delete;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    notification_flashlight = intent.getExtras().getString("notification_flashlight");
    notification_sos = intent.getExtras().getString("notification_sos");
    notification_delete = intent.getExtras().getString("notification_delete");

    if (notification_flashlight != null) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Flashlight", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    else if (notification_sos != null) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "SOS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    else if (notification_delete != null) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me? I don't know what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am posting the answer so it will help others as well. I was using **implicit intent** for broadcast receiver which Android Oreo does not suggest. So, I have to use **explicit intent** and after that it started working fine.

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<receiver android:name="com.appedia.flashlight.torch.Notification_Receiver" />
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public void NotificationItemsClickIntent()
{
    Intent notification_intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notification_intent, 0);

    Intent notification_deleted_intent = new Intent(this, Notification_Receiver.class);
    notification_deleted_intent.putExtra("notification_delete", "notification_delete");
    delete_pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, notification_deleted_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    /* Pending Intent for Notification Flashlight Button */
    //Intent with flashlight button for triggering Broadcast Receiver when clicked from notification bar
    Intent notification_flashlight_intent = new Intent(this, Notification_Receiver.class);
    notification_flashlight_intent.putExtra("notification_flashlight", "Flashlight");
    PendingIntent notification_flashlight_button = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,2,notification_flashlight_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_flashlight_button, notification_flashlight_button);

    /* Pending Intent for Notification SOS Button */
    //Intent with sos button for triggering Broadcast Receiver when clicked from notification bar
    Intent notification_sos_intent = new Intent(this, Notification_Receiver.class);
    notification_sos_intent.putExtra("notification_sos", "SOS");
    PendingIntent notification_sos_button = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,3,notification_sos_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_sos_button, notification_sos_button);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your broadcast receiver you must check for action and not `getExtras.getString()`

```
public class Notification_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

String notification_flashlight, notification_sos, notification_delete;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    notification_flashlight = intent.getAction() == "notification_flashlight";
    notification_sos =        intent.getAction() == "notification_sos";
    notification_delete =     intent.getAction() == "notification_delete";

    if (notification_flashlight != null && notification_flashlight == true) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Flashlight", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    else if (notification_sos != null && notification_sos== true) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "SOS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    else if (notification_delete != null && notification_delete == true) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: I have also tested it on Infinix device.